# Communication link failure from lambda to RDS Mysql connection

Tags: java, mysql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a lambda function from where I am trying to access RDS mysql schema but getting communication link failure exception.{"message":"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet successfully received from the server was 184 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 175 milliseconds ago.)"}

Security group in both lambda and RDS DB are same and they have same region as well. Security group is set for all traffic from IPV4 both for inbound and outbound

BasicDataSource destinationConnectionPool = getConnectionPool("admin", "password", "jdbc:mysql://<rds_host_url>", 10);

```
private BasicDataSource getConnectionPool(String userName, String dbPass, String jdbcUrl, int initialSize) {
    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    basicDataSource.setUsername(userName);
    basicDataSource.setPassword(dbPass);
    basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    basicDataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
    basicDataSource.setMaxIdle(initialSize);
    basicDataSource.setMinIdle(initialSize);
    basicDataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
    basicDataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    return basicDataSource;
}
```

Connection conn = connectionPool.getConnection();// this line giving error

Inbound and outbound rule in security group mention no specific ip or port

IP version  Type    Protocol    Port range  Source
IPv4            All traffic All         All             0.0.0.0/0

Comment: You have a problem with your security group.   Either the IPs you specified are in correct, or the ports opened are.

Comment: Have not mentioned any ip , it allows for all     ports     in inbound as well outbound rule                                                                                                                               IP version  Type  Protocol  Port range                Source 
IPv4   All traffic All   All    0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

It was actually ssl handshake issue "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)", resolved it by adding "useSSL=false" in jdbc url